# Why does adding DataTables break my page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatable, html-table

I've got a working page with four quadrants; three contain Chart.JS charts, and the other contains an HTML table.

I added DataTables to the page with these references:

```
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" />
```

Then I gave the html table an ID:

```
<table id="delperfTable">
```

And finally added the DataTablesification jQuery to the ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#delperfTable').DataTable();
    . . .
```

..and that causes three of the four quadrants to go blank (ironically, the HTML table quadrant is the only unaffected - either positively or negatively - by adding that line).

Chrome Dev Tools points to that last line of code shown, complaining "*Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function*"

?!? I'm referencing datatables, as shown, and jQuery, too; here are all my css and jquery references:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- Data Tables -->
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" />
```

What would make that happen? Some anomaly in my HTML table? It generates fine with "$('#delperfTable').DataTable();" commented out...

Here is the HTML table in greater context, although, based on the console error, I don't think my table's structure is really the issue:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="bottomright">
        <h2 class="sectiontext">Delivery Performance</h2>
        <table id="delperfTable">
            <tr>
                <th>PRO*ACT Distributor</th>
                <th>Restaurant Location</th>
                <th class="rightjustifytext">Avg Order Amount</th>
                <th class="rightjustifytext">Avg Package Count</th>
                <th class="rightjustifytext">Total Sales</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Sunrise FL</td>
                <td>A1A ALEWORKS - #4405 - ST. AUGUSTINE</td>
                <td class="rightjustifytext">$475.78</td>
                <td class="rightjustifytext">28.50</td>
                <td class="rightjustifytext">$1,903.10</td>
            </tr>
            . . .
        </table>
        . . .
    </div>
</div>
```

### UPDATE

My reference to the javascript is now:

```
<script href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

...and my table is now:

```
<table id="delperfTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>PRO*ACT Distributor</th>
            <th>Restaurant Location</th>
            <th class="rightjustifytext">Avg Order Amount</th>
            <th class="rightjustifytext">Avg Package Count</th>
            <th class="rightjustifytext">Total Sales</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Sunrise FL</td>
            <td>A1A ALEWORKS - #4405 - ST. AUGUSTINE</td>
            <td class="rightjustifytext">$475.78</td>
            <td class="rightjustifytext">28.50</td>
            <td class="rightjustifytext">$1,903.10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            . . . // table rows elided for brevity
        </tr>
        <tr class="bold">
            <td>TOTAL</td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="rightjustifytext">375.11</td>
            <td class="rightjustifytext">23.50</td>
            <td class="rightjustifytext">$7,966.68</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Yet it still looks as plain vanilla as ever - it doesn't seem to have been datatablized:

[image]

In fact, "turning on" DataTable this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#delperfTable').DataTable();
    $("body").on("click", "#btnGetData",
    . . .
```

...causes other parts of my page to fail (Chart.JS charts don't even display at all); commenting out "$('#delperfTable').DataTable();" causes all else to work again, even though, of course, no change is made to the html table.

### UPDATE 2

If I move the "$('#delperfTable').DataTable();" to the very last thing inside the ready function, it doesn't break the rest of the code; but it still does nothing.

I still see the "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function" err msg in the console.

Comment: No, it is capitalized in the err msg, as is the usage example at https://datatables.net/

Comment: Too add to Jason P's answer, datatables will not work without well defined tables so you're going to have to add `<thead>` and `<tbody>` to your structure.

Comment: I switched "link" to "script" per Jason P; I added thead and tbody sections, but still see no change in my table's presentation.

Comment: Looks like you're missing `<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>` after `jquery.dataTables.min.js`.   See [here](https://cdn.datatables.net/), click the Bootstrap button.

Comment: That was not exactly it, but led me to the solution: I had to change "href" to "src" in my reference of the dataTables javascript file. However, adding the dataTables.bootstrap completely hoses everything up, appearance-wise. Perhaps because I already have this above: <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: Replacing the prior css reference with the bootstrap one works fine, but adding the bootstrap js hoses everything up. So I obviously use just the former, and not the latter, although there seems to be no difference in appearance when using one cs over the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripts are included using a `<script>` tag, not a `<link>`

```
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" />
```

should be this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```